# VS Code terminated upon launch with code: -2147483645

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone else exexperiencing the same issue? I was using it last month and did not lauch the app during my vacation, and all suddenly I'm having this issue.
At this point I'm really frustrated so I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Steps tried:

- Rebooting the system: not working
- Uninstall and reinstall: not working
- Tried launching in cmd with all extension disabled: not working
- Tried VS code insider and this is working

For the regular VS code it just keeps crashing upon launching with the same error code.

Comment: see: [Frequent Crash - Reason: 'crashed', Code: '-2147483645' (github.com)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131714)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the link I provided, someone suggests to do: `code --verbose` (see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131714#issuecomment-907465852 ) Maybe you can redirect that to a file, and examine it for errors ?

Comment: @Luuk thanks for the info. I went through that but I did not see errors, or maybe I just don't understand the outcome of this. I will email them the crash report to see if they can help. Thanks again for the link.

Comment: you can also create an issue ticket using the `Help: Report Issue...` command. If you do, please link us to your issue ticket once it is created.

Comment: @starball, thank you very much for your input. I actually fix the issue by myself last night. What I did was to remove all the VS code related folder under appdata roaming folder, and then a fresh reinstall. Downside was I lost all my project (I forgot to backup), but I'm using VS code mainly for learning programming so not too much was really lost.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this error, delete all *Visual Studio Code* caches.

If you are using **Windows**, go to the `%APPDATA%/Code` folder

If you are using **macOS**, go to the folder `~/Library/Application Support/Code`

Then delete all folders with the word `Cache` or `Cached` in the name.

After deleting these folders, start *Visual Studio Code*. It should now open without error.

This error appeared on my computer after an incorrect reboot.